# Execution of neo4j cypher query from spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, neo4j, repository

Hi neo4j/spring boot masters

I am new to spring boot and I am trying to execute a cypher query without the `@Query` annotation.

I can see that my requirement is possible with `entityManage.createQuery()` in spring repository (javax)

But the adaptor for **neo4j** doesn't seem to have an entity Manager.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I used the neo4j java driver in my spring boot as described at [Using Neo4j from Java](https://neo4j.com/developer/java/)

This is maybe not what neo4j offers first, but i feel it is simple. You can also use it without transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, have a look at `org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.Neo4jClient` - specifically the `query()` method - if you have setup neo4j correctly in Spring then you can simply inject this class.